# Drupal9: installing problem PHP-encryption library

Tags: encryption, drupal-9

for encryption data i wants to use in Drupal9 the PHP-encryption library width "REAL AES" Module. But Drupal can not find the PHP-encryption library while enaple the "REAL AES" module.

It is very new to use PHP-encryption in Drupal9, so i think there can be a bug in code or in readme.txt of Installationprozess.

So my main question is: In Which folder do i have to install PHP-encryption-Code?
I installed by the hint of REAME.txt "composer require defuse/php-encryption". But it was unclear in which folder:

1. In Root of Server? or
2. In Drupal-Folder sites/all/libraries/php-encryption or
3. In Drupal-Folder of REal AES Module: modules/real_aes/defuse/
4. Question: Drupal9 works with composer. Do I have to activate the PHP-encryption library especially? for ex. in main composer.json ?

Thank you for your help, because I m new in Drupal9.

After activating the REAl AEs Module in Drupal9, the module wants to use the library. That does not work, so it shows the errormessage

> Please install the Defuse PHP-encryption library via Composer. See README.txt

I use this Drupalmodule:
https://www.drupal.org/project/real_aes

PHP-encryption library:
https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption

---

So now im looking in the code of php-encryption library und found the Problem in checking the existens of a Class which causes the problem.

so this becomes false instead of true:

> if (class_exists('\Defuse\Crypto\Crypto'))

in https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2613682-3.patch
So the result is the text above "Please install the Defuse PHP-encryption library via Composer"...

but the class Crypto is in folder /defuse/src/Crypto.php

```
<?php

namespace Defuse\Crypto;

use Defuse\Crypto\Exception as Ex;

class Crypto
{
```

Comment: Please share more details, like the code involved and the **exact** error message you are facing

Comment: Thanks for Help! I edit my post

Comment: Please edit your question to contain **all** relevant information. What does that Readme tell you? What have you tried to resolve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Now it works:

I had to install php-encryption-library with composer in folder of the module!